# Boostrap Simple Page not responsive on mobile device

Tags: css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

My simple bootstrap page is not responsive on my iphone, but it is with google chrome on my computer.

Zoom is not good on iphone and this is my viewport :

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Screenshot iphone :
[iphone](http://ujjsm.free.fr/img/iphonescreenshot.png)

Screenshot chrome :
[chrome](http://ujjsm.free.fr/img/chromescreenshot.png)

If someone can help me,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), you are making your website like a native app which is not recommended by them. if that's the case, You are omitting a couple of attributes .

> You can disable zooming capabilities on mobile devices by adding
>   user-scalable=no to the viewport meta tag. This disables zooming,
>   meaning users are only able to scroll, and results in your site
>   feeling a bit more like a native application. Overall, we don't
>   recommend this on every site, so use caution!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, 
   user-scalable=no">
```

so if you don't want the native app like website, you can just go for this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

try this: instead of 1.0 put 1 for initial scale;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Comment: thanks but same problem with "user-scalable=no" or "initial-scale=1"

Comment: are you sure your css file is loading properly? @pldlt show us some html or post it on jsfiddle or send us a link to the website

Comment: try the last option of my answer @pldlt the last line, replace your code for the viewport with that and you will probably figure out how come this isn;t working on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this meta tag, instead:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Can you show your page code? Your snippet is not working!

Comment: Seems like your CSS code is not from Bootstrap. Try to put this link from Bootstrap CDN above your current style:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: ever try but same problem

Comment: I testes on Chrome and Firefox browsers on my phone and worked fine. Maybe the problem is a responsive compatibility with Safari on iPhone. I just tested on my iPod 4g on Safari and works fine, too.